# Footnotes within \paragraph

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs

I am writing my first university paper in Latex and I am getting compile errors when trying to use `\footnote{}` within the `\paragraph{}` command.

My document looks roughly like:

```
\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is confirmed by Aristotle ~\footnote{Aris. Pol. 8.12.3}.}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the error message:

```
tex/config/pdftex.map}]
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.29    \paragraph
{The state of the evidence is highly fragmentary.  The two m...
```

This is the next paragraph.

The internet tells me that using footnotes is not possible within `\paragraph{}`, but I really like the formatting it gives (although `\footnote{}` works outside the paragraph environment.  Is there a package I can use or a good workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit odd to have a footnote in a section heading, but if you do, you need to supply a version without the footnote for the table of contents and page headings.

Here `\paragraph` is used directly to keep the example small but it is a 4th level heading so should only be used after `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\paragraph[This is confirmed by Aristotle]
{This is confirmed by Aristotle ~\footnote{Aris. Pol. 8.12.3}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ashley do you really have that deep a section structure in your document?

Comment: Not really, to be honest.  It's a 3000 word paper with a few sections, each for a new Greek Tyrant. I have, however, set a number of parameters on the paragraphs to make it fit in with my university's style guide.

Comment: @Ashley it's really unfortunate that latex calls it `\paragraph` rather than `\subsubsubsection` lots of people use it when they probably wouldn't have, but too late to change it now:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really really need to this the general mechanism is `\footnotemark` in the title, and then `\footnotetext{text}` later, outside the title.  The catch is the `\footnotemark` needs to be proceeded by `\protect` and you need to fix the counter.  However, you can do something simpler: give `\paragraph` an optional argument too.  That optional argument is for the version of the title to go in the table of contents etc., but for paragraphs this material does not appear so you can just use `[]`:

[image: Sample titles]

[image: Sample foots]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{This is confirmed by Aristotle\protect\footnotemark.}
\refstepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{Aris. Pol. 8.12.3}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}

\paragraph[]{This is confirmed by Aristotle\footnote{Aris. Pol. 8.12.3}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the first version  will put a footnotemark with no footnote in the table of contents (if the toc goes to level 4)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed - but standard styles don't do that by default and this does not look like the type of heading that should be in the table of contents anyway.

Comment: Because it shouldn't be using `\paragraph` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `\protect` before `\footnote`.

Comment: That would put a footnote also in the  table of contents (if the toc goes to level 4)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.